# How do you connect two command words in python?

Tags: python, printing, connect

```
import os
blah = 'Umm'

print('blah')
os.system('say blah')
"""so I want to make these two things linked, 
so that whenever I print something, it says that something
"""
```

I wanna link these two things, so that whenever I call upon print() it also says what I printed.

Please excuse my (possible) misuse of terminology.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's difficult to tell what you are asking for. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Well, the obvious approach would be to make a function...

Comment: I have basically written a really long piece of code and want an easier way rather than going through manually changing each and every print

Comment: Are you saying that you want to print data in a variable plus the name of the variable that its in?

Comment: Literally say - Is this a text to voice thing?

Comment: No I wanna print the data and then using  os.system()  make my mac say what I printed. Preferably simultaneously

Comment: Yep its on terminal on mac a command. If you enter say followed by anything it will say that thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a function, then its just a simple case of finding and replacing all of your `print` with `printSay`

```
import os

def printSay(word):
    print(word)
    os.system('say {word}'.format(word=word))

# Usage
printSay("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run `say` as a subprocess and write the data to its stdin. I did this on linux with espeak, but I think I got the say command right.

```
import subprocess

say = subprocess.Popen(["say", "-f", "-"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

def myprint(*args):
    print(*args)
    say.stdin.write((' '.join(args) + '\n').encode('utf-8'))

myprint("hello there")
```